# default value to column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, default-value

I run:

**rails generate migration AddHidemsgColumnToPublishers hide_msg:boolean**

and the next file was created:

```
class AddHidemsgColumnToPublishers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :publishers, :hide_msg, :boolean
  end
end
```

I want to set a default value into `hide_msg` by false.

so I tried:

**rails generate migration add_default_value_to_hide_msg**

```
class AddDefaultValueToHideMsg < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :publishers, :hide_msg, :boolean, :default => false
  end

  def down
    change_column :publishers, :hide_msg, :boolean, :default => nil
  end
end
```

but I got errors:

```
rake db:migrate
==  AddHidemsgColumnToPublishers: migrating ===================================
-- add_column(:publishers, :hide_msg, :boolean, {:default=>false})
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  column "hide_msg" of relation "publishers" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "publishers" ADD COLUMN "hide_msg" boolean DEFAULT 'f'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a suggestion.... do not set the default value in the database, as you might face some problems if you want to change it latter on.

I think it is better if you set it in your model.

```
before_save :set_default_high_msg
def set_default_high_msg
  self.high_msg ||= false
end
```

or even in your controller:

```
 def new
   @publisher = Publisher.new
   @publisher.high_msg ||= false
 ...
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rake db:migrate
==  AddHidemsgColumnToPublishers: migrating ===================================
-- add_column(:publishers, :hide_msg, :boolean, {:default=>false})
```

Above thing means its trying to create colimn which already exist. If you check the class name `AddHidemsgColumnToPublishers` . This means it trying to execute your first migration in which you don't have `default` value. This clearly indicates you are doing something wrong.

`publishers` already has column `hide_msg`. So check the `table description` in `db` console. If you don't have any values in `hide_msg` then you can manually `drop` the column and re-run the `rake db:migrate`. Or you can keep that column as it is and just create migration to add `default value`.

```
change_column_default :publishers, :hide_msg, false
```

Doc: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_default